# Responsively collapse left and right cells downwards, middle cell upwards, with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, html-table

I have a column of text on the left, and image in the middle, and another column of text on the right. On small screen sizes, I'd like the image to be displayed first, then the text columns to display below.

How can I do this?

My 3 columns look like:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3"><p>Text1</p></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"><img src="inmiddleorabove.png"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3"><p>Text2</p></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this you need? Try it:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">
        <img src="inmiddleorabove.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3 col-lg-pull-6">
        <p>Text1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
        <p>Text2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to set the order of columns for small screen first,
then use [column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) to push or pull your columns for other screen size.

Hope this help.

See it here: http://bootply.com/y4N70nGh40

Comment: Nice example of push pull.